# Calculate expected value and variance of normally distributed..

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

> $X_1,.., X_n$ are independent, identical distributed random variables.
>   They are continuous, too. Let $$\bar{X}= \frac{1}{n} \cdot
> (X_1+..+X_n)$$
>
> Determine the expected value and variance of $\bar{X}$ if $$X_i \text{
> is normally distributed, } X_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$$

I don't know how do it good?

I check expected value of normal distribution on internet. This is

$$E(X) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx$$

Now I try form it so I have good solutin

$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}d\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}= 0$$

It work like this? But no idea about variance..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Linearity of Expectation,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X] &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \mathbb{E}[X_i]\\
&= \frac{1}{n} (n\mu) = \mu
\end{align}

As $X_i$ are i.i.d.,
\begin{align}
\text{Var}[X] &= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_i \text{Var}[X_i]\\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}(n\sigma^2)\\
&= \sigma^2/n
\end{align}

As a bonus, $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I do all wrong because I just handed it in.. But better I have solution and understand for exam because can ask similar question. Can pls also show for this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547210/determine-the-expected-value-and-variance-of-barx/2547232#2547232

I don't understanded answer of other people